# How to debug C4722 #import referenced a type from a missing type library; 'missing-type' used as a placeholder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com, atl

I'm getting the following error when I build a Visual Studio C++ project on Azure Pipeline (Microsoft-hosted agent).

> C4722 #import referenced a type from a missing type library;
> 'missing-type' used as a placeholder

I learned what the error is on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4772?view=msvc-160).

However, I'm still wondering if there is any way to debug this error further, particularly to know what is the "type" or "missing type library" by name?

Comment: What is the .tlb you're using? What you can do is use the procmon tool from sysinternals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon filter by cl.exe (VC compiler) and file access, and look for CreateFile operations on .tlb files with a NAME_NOT_FOUND result, usually not far after a successful CreateFile operation on the imported .tlb.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for your solution. The library in question is MSPPT.OLB. I import other libraries before importing it. So it should work, but it does not. I'll try your solution tonight, and get back to you.

Comment: I can successfully import MSPPT.OLB with these definitions: https://pastebin.com/raw/vgG9qGkS (paths must be adapted)